# Anyone have a Tag Suggestion Component for ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tagging

I'm wondering if anyone has seen a tagging suggestion componet for Asp.Net.
Simliar to the StackOverFlow, ZenDesk, Delicious Tagging Sugestion (Autocomplete, Click to delete, etc)

I'm sure we could put one together...but it seams like it would be prime for a 'Best-in-class' componet product. So I think it must be out there.

If not, I'm someone's first customer!
Thx
CM

Answer (score 1):

I like [TextBoxList](http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/textboxlist/Demo/)

[image: TextBoxList screenshot]
<sub>(source: [miniajax.com](http://miniajax.com/uu_files/ss_textboxlist.gif))</sub>

**Edit**: just found another one! [AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

[AutoSuggest jQuery Plugin screenshot http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/9291/51529959.jpg](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/9291/51529959.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

We were in the same boat as you. A tagging component seemed like something that was perfect for a third party. We looked and everything we came across just wasn't right. After spending half a day looking for something to work, we went and spent a couple of days writing our own component.